# Wordpress Remove the query string from images

Tags: wordpress, image, optimization, media-queries, media

I'm optimizing my website and after some testing I found this:

**Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources:**

I already fixed it for my JS and CSS files with this code:

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
    $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
        return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

But for some reason almost all my images have Media Queries behind the extension too.

**/wp-content/uploads/drupal-hosting-vergelijken.png?26f7af**

**/wp-content/plugins/custom-share-buttons-with-floating-sidebar/images/fb.png?26f7af**

Is there a solution to prevent or remove this?

Comment: you can do preg_replace and remove all query var from the image link, but you need to be specific where did this image come from, if its from post content, you can pass a content filter to handle this.

Comment: Tnx for your reply. The images are just all the images from that page. Not specific 1 image but all of my images are like that.

Comment: Ok, my bet.... spending hours to find out and it was just a option I checked in W3 total:

Comment: Prevent caching of objects after settings change in Media & Other files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **W3 Total Cache**, goto its Page Cache settings:
From the **WP left-hand menu**, Click:
**Performance** --> **Browser Cache**
(*-- not the link at the top of the W3TC General Settings)*.
Then UNCHECK:

`[] Prevent caching of objects after settings change 
Whenever settings are changed, a new query string will be generated and appended to objects allowing the new policy to be applied.`

This removed query strings from static Images on my website !!
However, a few other js and css files with query strings still remain.

I must try the solution provided above for the js and css files :-)

I found a plugin that removes js and css file queries.
It's code is that same as you provided above :-)
Yet may be more accessible for some:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/